# Difference between "vecchio" and "anziano"

Tags: difference

What is the difference between *vecchio* and *anziano*? They both mean "old". Which one would you use to say a place is old, *vecchio* or *anziano*?

Comment: If the current trend continues, sooner or later we will address elderly people as "diversamente giovani". Anyway, if you are talking about a place, you may use "vecchio" or, if it applies, "antico". If you are looking for a refined word, you may also use "vetusto".

Comment: Note that referring to your parents calling them "i miei vecchi" is generally considered an affectionate expression.

Comment: "Anziano" only applies to people, not objects or places. For places you can use "vecchio". As gd1 says.

Comment: Although it's not *that* simple ;)

Comment: At the cost of getting some criticism, I'd say that "anziano" does NOT generally mean "old", but rather "aged" or "elderly", and is only used when talking about senior people to show some respect. Using "vecchio" for a person can be (depending on the context) rude, especially when used as substantive ("un vecchio"). Of course there are exceptions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, it depends.

*Anziano* is always inappropriate for places, unless we are under an allegory or some sort of personification, or any other figure of speech, however sophisticated.

If you are referring to the old bus stop, and there is a new one 100 meters ahead, you should say "la *vecchia* fermata", as opposed to the new one. For a crumbling building, you may say "quell'edificio è molto *vecchio*", even if I would prefer to use a more precise term, such as *cadente*, *fatiscente*, or *pericolante*.

But if you are talking about an old church, you should use *antico* or opt for a high-register term such as *vetusto*. "Una chiesa *vecchia*" is a poor word choice: either you want to say "la *vecchia* chiesa" (because there is a new one) or "una chiesa *antica*". If you say "Quella chiesa è molto *vecchia*" people may think you are pointing out that the church was built in the Seventies, and some handymen have to be hired because it needs some **refurbishment**. Well, that's really not the case.

Answer (score 2):

> - **Vecchio** is a general term meaning old. When referring to an old man **anziano** is the term that is generally considered more respectful.
> - If you want to refer to a place **vecchio** is the term you should use. It has the same connotation as in English meaning both a place that is many years old and a place were you used to go, *your old school!*.

Comment: About your second point, I'd say... *not quite always*. I am not a native English speaker - so correct me if needed - but I do not find anything wrong with "That church is very old", whereas "Quella chiesa è molto vecchia" is quite inappropriate if you want to say that it is ... *ancient*. People may think you are pointing out that the church was built some decades ago and needs some refurbishment.

Answer (score -1):

Same as with "old" and "elder/ly".  Elder/Elderly (*anziano*), old (*vecchio*).  The former applies to individuals the second with either. Some religious sects and orders have anziani, viz. "elders."

Answer (score -1):

Vecchio - also means **"Elder"**; used to distinguish two important persons of the same family sharing the same name and surname. Example: Bruegel the Elder/Pliny the Elder/Cosimo dei Medici, il Vecchio - Cosimo dei Medici, the Elder - to distinguish this person from say another Cosimo of the Medici family who may be younger (in Italian Novello). Likewise could also mean an elder of a tribe or council elder (i.e an Alderman). Interestingly the Arab sheikh means old-man or elder. Plural of the Italian noun (and adjective) Vecchio is Vecchi (Elders, Old-men)